# User password is being changed when the user clicks the email verification link

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am building api authentication routes using nodejs and express. The login and registration routes work perfectly until I try verifying a user by sending them a verification link via email. The user password is being changed, therefore after the email being verified, the user is unable to login. I don't get what is happening to my code. I am encrypting my passwords using bcrypt but when try using unencrypted passwords, everything works. The password is only changed after email verification when I use bcrypt encryption! I need help please!

Here is my code:

User Model:

```
import { Schema, model } from "mongoose";
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    Admin: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'name field required!']
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'email field required'],
        unique: [true, 'email already taken!']
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'password field required']
    },
    verified: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    verificationToken: {
        type: String
    },
    addresses: [
        {
            name: String,
            mobileNo: String,
            houseNo: String,
            streetNo: String,
            landMark: String,
            city: String,
            country: String,
            postalCode: String
        }
    ],
    orders: [
        {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Order'
        }
    ]
}, { timestamps: true });

/** fire function before saving document */
UserSchema.pre('save', async function (next) {
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt();
    this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt);
    next();
});

/** fire function after saving document */
UserSchema.post("save", async (doc, next) => {
    console.log("User has been created!", doc);
    next();
});

/** fire this function to login the user */
UserSchema.statics.login = async function (email, password) {
    const user = await this.findOne({ email });
    
    if (user) {
        const auth = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

        if (auth) {
            return user;
        }
        throw Error('Wrong password!')
    }

    throw Error('Email does not exist!')
}


const User = model('User', UserSchema);

export default User;
```

Controllers:

```
import crypto from 'crypto';
import User from "../models/User.js";
import sendEmailVerification from '../lib/nodemailer.js';
import { createToken, maxAge } from "../lib/token.js";

/** 
 * ! Register New User
 */
const registerUser = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { name, email, password } = req.body;

        /** check if user exists */
        const userExists = await User.findOne({ email });

        if (userExists) {
            return res.status(401).json({message: 'User already exists!'})
        }


        const user = await User.create({
            name,
            email,
            password,
            verificationToken: crypto.randomBytes(20).toString('hex')
        });

        /** send verification email */
        await sendEmailVerification(user.email, user.verificationToken);

        return res.status(200).json({message: 'User registration successful'})
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return res.status(500).json({error: error.message})
    }
}

/**
 * ? Verify verification token
 */
const verifyToken = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { token } = req.params;

        /** find user with the given verification token */
        const user = await User.findOne({ verificationToken: token });
        if (!user) {
            return res.status(401).json({message: 'Invalid verification token!'})
        }

        /** mark as verified */
        user.verified = true;
        user.verificationToken = undefined;

        await user.save();

        res.status(200).json({message: 'User token has been verified!'})
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return res.status(500).json({message: 'Token verification failed!'})
    }
}


/**
 * ! Login User;
 */
const loginUser = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { email, password } = req.body;

        /** check if user is verified */
        const user = await User.login(email, password);

        const token = await createToken(user._id, user.email, user.Admin, user.name);
        res.cookie("authToken", token, { maxAge: maxAge * 1000, httpOnly: true})
        res.status(200).json({ user });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return res.status(500).json({error: error.message})
    }
}

export {
    registerUser,
    verifyToken,
    loginUser
}
```

Routes:

```
import { Router } from "express";
import { loginUser, registerUser, verifyToken } from "../controllers/auth.js";


const router = Router();

/**
 * ! Create New User
 */
router.post("/register", registerUser);

/**
 * ? Verify verification token
 */
router.get('/verify/:token', verifyToken);

/**
 * ! Login User;
 */
router.post("/login", loginUser);

export default router;
```

Comment: Can you please share the error

Comment: `The password is only changed after email verification` after it is sent, or after the user uses the verify token to verify the email address?

Comment: The password changes after user verifies the email.

Comment: is it possible that `UserSchema.pre('save'` is being executed more than once? add some console.log's to see what code is being run at each step, you may gain some debugging information

Comment: Let me give that a go and see!

Comment: It's because you are rehashing the password every time. So when you save the user to process email verification, you are hashing the hash. The way I normally solve this is that I don't use a field `password` but instead a field `hashedPassword`, and only if the property `password` (which is not a real field) is set then it updates `hashedPassword` on save.

Comment: @JaromandaX thank you for your help. I highly appreciate. It really helped me solve my problem.

Comment: @CherryDT yes this definitely works. Thank you so much!